# Can't edit README.md in GitHub

Tags: github, readme

I have just created a new repository in GitHub and I wanted to change the Readme file, however the "Commit Changes" button is just greyed out, as shown below.

[image]

As well as this, when I click on "Preview" to view how it would look with Markdown, nothing happens, it just stays on the "Edit File" tab. Why is this not working?

Comment: You probably set up the repo to now allow commits directly to main. Create a branch and submit a pull request

Comment: @mousetail I have the same problem even on a new branch. "Create a new branch for this commit and start a pull request" doesn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try disabling adblockers. I found [this post](https://github.community/t/commit-changes-button-not-working/1656/9) on github community I tried toggling my adblockers and found it was ghostery breaking the site.

Edit: Ghostery specifically breaks the page by blocking Adobe Experience Cloud. This can be resolved by either setting the github site as trusted or by enabling that tracker on the github site (as I've done).

[image: My Ghostery settings for github.com]

Comment: Yes, this was the problem, with ghostery as well! Thank you!